# Get php variable containing date from jquery datepicker

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, datepicker

I have a jquery datepicker defined like this :

HTML/php:

```
<input id="datepicker" name="date" placeholder="Date" />
```

Javascript:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
    $("#datepicker").datepicker();
    });
</script>
```

This works perfectly but i need to get the date in a php variable. I tried $_POST["date"] but this does not work. Could you help me ? Thanks !

Comment: What does your `<form>` tag look like?

Comment: The <form> tag is like this :
  
    <form method="post" class=post_reunion" action="postReunion.php">

Comment: do a F12 on you browser and go to network tab and see what is transmitted when you submit your form. Maybe your field is empty or something else.

Comment: @micael Well, the `input` element is named `date`, the form is submitted as a `POST` request, and you grab the value using `$_POST["date"]`. It should work. What does the datepicker field contain when you submit the form?

Comment: @ David Jacquel @SverriM.Olsen Actually, i checked what is in the $_POST["date"] and this contains a negative integer number...

Comment: nothing wrong with what is shown, problem is elsewhere. Is this an ajax post?

Comment: I agree with charlietfl. Can you post the full code? Or at least more of it?

Comment: Well here is my html/php code : http://codeshare.io/nVrY9

Comment: I see you calling jQuery functions, but I don't see any jQuery libraries...

Comment: Yes i did not mention it because none of the jQuery functions are used in this page. (i guess you are talking about this <script type="text/javascript" src="script/modif-prive.js"></script>)

Comment: You include a call to jQuery datpicker at the top of the code you provided.

Comment: you have a `table` tag with `ul` as children which is invalid...show your source html from browser dev tools. Browser may be reconstructing your form due to invalid markup

Comment: @sharf Yes, sorry here is the code of the query datepicker http://codeshare.io/pdAIm

Comment: @charlietfl Yes, i removed the table tag but this unfortunately didn't solve

Answer (score 0):

The problem is solved, I don't really know where the problem came from. I still use $_POST["date"] to get the date, then I convert it from dd/mm/yyyy to yyyy-mm-dd (because my sql request requires this format) and it works..
Anyway, thanks everyone !